# A SpriteKit CCFollow alternative?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, sprite-kit

I have read that cocos has a method called CCFollow that change the node position accordingly to the position of a another node, something like "change che background position to follow the player position". In SpriteKit there's something similar? Or the only way is to modify the Node position manually or by an action?

EDIT

I have tried to move by action like moveTo, it works but in my game i have to move a large background image and some physics shape (that are the bonduaries of my racetrack). Moving the node that containt all my game with an skaction works but it cause jitters in iphone4 (even with a constant 30 fps, it seems a too cpu intese works, almost like 60% ). Until now the only solution is to simplify and reduce racetrack dimensions but i'm searching some others solutions... I have read about CCFollow,so i think that maybe this is an optimized method that solve my troubles...

Comment: try issuing a moveTo action every frame with the position of the target. In cocos2d that won't work due to a delay in action execution, but it may work in SK.

Comment: iPhone 4 is slow - consider that it's only ~33% faster than iPhone 3GS but has to serve a Retina display with 4 times as many pixels. Also 30 fps will never look smooth. Have you tested that the framerate only drops when you move the background compared to when it is static?

Comment: the frame rate drops when i move the physics bonduary of the track,if i deactivate this bonduaries the scroll is smooth...

Comment: Is that a static (dynamic=NO) body that you are moving? This may cause a high CPU usage because internally the physics engine isn't prepared for static bodies changing their position, triggering some internal recalculations.

Comment: thank you ,is correct but i have already setted dynamic to NO where i can

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be changing the camera position. Instead of using a large image as background (this is highly not recommended)

Please refer to this under "Moving the Camera" section.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/CodeExplainedAdventure/KeepingUptoDate/KeepingUptoDate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013140-CH9-SW1

Comment: "Moving the Camera" section talk about a method to move the worldNode position to simulate the movement of a Camera,moving the worldNode position will move the physicsbody also. Pratically is the thing that already do...